# C++ MacOs Создать окно

Tags: c++, objective-c, opengl, macos

Как создать окно на MacOs используя **только** `OpenGl`, `C++` и `Objective-C(++)`. Последнее не желательно. (Я не знаю как в `CMakeLists.txt` прописать его, обычно в проектах с `Objective-C`, его там нету, а в `src/` он есть).

Comment: я не специалист по маку но почему бы вам не использовать GLUT https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLUT

Comment: Я его не использую потому, что считаю лучше самому написать, чтоб не тащить за собой эту грязь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам годится приложение с GUI, то используйте NSOpenGlView. Если же вам принципиально использовать без графиечкого интерфейса, то меньше всего "грязи" будет при использовании glut или glaux.

https://developer.apple.com/opengl/ - тут есть соответствующая документация, рекомендации и примеры.

А на тему objective-c, почему Вы не хотите использовать xcode?

Comment: Я на linux сижу =) Просто, нужно кросс платформенное приложение (игровой движок пишу).

Comment: А на счет GUI, оно мне не нужно. Только окно и OpenGL контекст.

Comment: по опыту написания движков - движок и интерфейс должны иметь возможность работать независимо, поэтому не стоит привязываться к реализации GUI - используйте стандартный OpenGL, а GUI  уже специфичную для целевой платформы. Попробуйте Qt - там кроссплатформенность поддерживается на более высоком уровне.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, GUI я делаю без привязки к какой-либо либе. Но ведь то что я хочу сделать, как-то реализовано в той же QT или SDL. Но как?

Comment: скорее всего через системные низкоуровневые средства вроде драйвера OpenGL, причем часто оптимальнее, чем это может сделать человек без определенных навыков, опыта и знаний. Как правило оптимальность и универсальность вещи не совместимы, потому как оптимизация происходит как правило под особенности конкретной платформы или даже устройства.